# MongoDB LINQ: Count with predicate inside Where not supported?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a collection of documents which look a bit like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620d91300adfc5baaafc3006"
  },
  "Results": [
    {
      "LabelIndex": 18,
      "Label": "modal",
      "Probability": 2.264034495769797e-26
    },
    {
      "LabelIndex": 10,
      "Label": "galaxy",
      "Probability": 2.4459039011662245e-34
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query this collection with LINQ with this query:

```
var results = documents
    .Where(x => x.Results.Count(y => y.Probability > .7) > 1)
    .ToList();
```

However this results in:

```
InvalidOperationException
Count({document}{Results}.Where(({document}{Probability} > 0.7))) is not supported.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hunch I thought that the LINQ provider wasn't using the aggregate pipeline, so I rewrote my query to:

```
var results = mcips
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Image = x.Image,
        Results = x.Results.Where(y => y.Probability > .7)
    })
    .Where(x => x.Results.Count() > 1)
    .ToList();
```

This works, but it'd still be nice to understand *why* the original query doesn't, and if there's an easier way to fix this.